# Selenium PHP Chrome Webdriver Issue

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to get started using Selenium with Chrome, i've had no previous trouble dealing with Selenium+Firefox, but i cannot seem to launch a Chrome browser now - every time I try, a Firefox browser appears instead.

Here is my setup:

```
$web_driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe");
$session = $web_driver->session('chrome');
```

I realise the first line is likely not to be correct. But i cannot think of how else to initiate Chrome.

Note: I have already downloaded the chrome web driver.

Here are the sources i used:
http://edvanbeinum.com/using-selenium-2-phpunit-to-automate-browser-testing
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Many thanks.

Comment: What other code are you using (post it's entirety, or at least trim it down to the fewest lines possible)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 $session = $web_driver->session('googlechrome');
```

instead of

```
 $session = $web_driver->session('chrome');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/ChromeDriver) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver).

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::htmlUnitWithJS();
{
  // For Chrome
  $options = new ChromeOptions();
  $prefs = array('download.default_directory' => 'c:/temp');
  $options->setExperimentalOption('prefs', $prefs);
  $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome(); 
  $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
}
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)